# How to use Hiptest publisher in test automation using selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

I'm using Hiptest platform to write Gherkin based stories and ACs for our projects in Hiptest. After my research, I also found that there is possibility that I can also download the QA automation test script in Java language that I can run and execute with Selenium Web Driver.

I also export the script from Hiptest using Hiptest Publisher service but it only contains blank template structure in which my automation engineer team needs to manually write automation business logic (like open the url in web browser, find element by id, click on button etc.)But in Hiptest documentation in website (i.e. https://docs.hiptest.net/define-the-right-level-for-your-action-words/), I found that if I create our action words as low level (leaf action words) and then export the script using Hiptest Publisher service in Java, I might have all automation business logic already written.

Again this is my understanding by reading the documentation from the given link.But my challenge is I don't know how to write leaf low level action words in Hiptest.Can anyone help me in this case and show me a path on how I can write leaf low level action words in hiptest, so that after writing in such manner when I export the automation script in Java, I can directly execute it using Selenium Web Driver (and my automation team don't need to do any modification in downloaded script)?

Waiting for your quick response on the same at your earliest

Answer (score 1):

If you use low-level action words, you'll have the possibility the directly export Seleniuml-IDE code, but I would not advise to do it this way (and I'm the one who wrote the documentation you are referring to ;) this is some doc I wrote for people who only wanted to use Selenium IDE inside Firefox).

What I would suggest you is to keep you action words at a high-level (something like  for example) and then generate the action words and fill in the blanks (or let the QA team fill in the blanks).
One quick way to do that is to use Selenium IDE to record each action word and generate Java code that can then be placed in the skeletons generated by hiptest-publisher.